# JS templating in Craft CP

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, garnish

I'm writing a plugin where I need to render some semi-complex HTML clientside at runtime (all inside the CP).

Does Garnish (or any other library/framework/JS-thingamabob shipped with Craft) offer any built-in JS templating functionality a'la [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template)?

Comment: Is the HTML you need to render in Twig templates?

Comment: Not really, rendering serverside doesn't really make sense in this case as all of the data will be clientside. The plan is to use ```craft()->templates->includeJs()``` to inject the raw HTML template on pageload, before compiling it in my plugin's JS without $.html()'ing myself to death :) Just wondering if Craft ships with any JS templating functionality, or if I'd need to include Handlebars, Underscore or the like with my plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only JS library that ships with Craft (besides the Craft-specific [Garnish](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Garnish)) is jQuery. Of course, jQuery is a helpful JS library, but by no means a full-fledged framework. Fortunately, adding a separate JS library is painfully easy!

**How to CDN from a Twig template...**

```
{% includeJsFile '//full/path/to/cdn.js' %}
```

**How to CDN from PHP...**

```php
craft()->templates->includeJsFile('//full/path/to/cdn.js');
```

When you use [**`includeJsFile`**](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/includejsfile), it wraps your path in a standard `<script>` tag... It doesn't matter where the file is, as long as the path is valid.

Keep in mind, a PHP call will take effect in both the back-end *and* front-end of your site. So to keep the file loaded *only* in your CP, make sure to wrap a conditional around it:

```php
if (craft()->request->isCpRequest()) {
    craft()->templates->includeJsFile('//full/path/to/cdn.js');
}
```

Don't want to CDN? No problem! The best place to store local JS files would be in a `resources` folder:

```
/craft
  /plugins
    /myplugin
      /resources
        /js
          /handlebars.min.js
```

In that case, you can use [**`includeJsResource`**](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/resources) instead of `includeJsFile`.

Comment: Crazy good answer, Lindsey.  I don't want to edit because I rarely get which word to use right, but I'm pretty sure it's "will take affect" instead of "will take effect".

Comment: Thanks Brad! If that's your biggest complaint, I can work with that. Also, [I actually nailed the grammar too](https://wordwatchtowers.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/take-affect-or-take-effect/). :)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply, Lindsey. I feel Mustache/Handlebars is a pretty good fit for Craft, so CDN'ing that would be a good solution. Also, there is actually a [JS port for Twig](https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js/), though I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in client side/JS templating available out of the box that I know of. You can always render Twig templates via Ajax by [calling a plugin controller](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#posting-to-controller-actions-with-javaScript) and returning a rendered HTML string, but that doesn't seem to fit your use case.

Comment: In most cases, this would definitely be the answer. However, the trip server side to compile a template seems a bit redundant when all the data is on the client side, and there are no interactions w/ Craft services etc.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/). We've successfully been able to share JS templating with Craft templates, and it's worked *pretty* well. Not without it's caveats, though. Mostly coming from slight syntax differences and available filters.

Comment: Sweet, I'll check out Swig – thanks! Have you tested the Twig.js subset? Curious how the two compare.

Comment: Twig.js is meant as a port, Swig just happens to use a pretty much identical syntax.I've used both

Comment: Twig.js is probably more easily interoperable with Craft templates as it's meant to be a port.

One thing I plan to do eventually is make a craft extension for twig.js and/or swig, that would give you all the filters and template functionality you would have in craft, so that you can truly use 1 template for php and js rendered templates.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your input, Tim! There's also a [Grunt plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-twig-render) which uses Twig.js – a Craft extension for the latter would open up some interesting possibilities.